# how to navigate to pages when tap on this icon

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have already created screens then .i need to navigate with pages when i tap on this icon.could you please give some support.

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(

        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex=index;
          });
        },
          currentIndex:selectedIndex,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Ionicons.home_outline),
            label: "Home",

          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Ionicons.list_outline),
            label: "TODO",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Ionicons.time_outline),
            label: "TIME TABLE",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Ionicons.person_outline),
            label: "ABOUT",
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class BottomNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
      const BottomNavigation({super.key});
    
      @override
      _BottomNavigationState createState() => _BottomNavigationState();
    }
    
    class _BottomNavigationState extends State<BottomNavigation> {
      int selectedIndex = 0;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final List<Widget> btmNavBar = [
          const Home(),
          const TODO(),
          const TIMETABLE(),
           const ABOUT(),
         
        ];
        return Scaffold(
          body: btmNavBar[selectedIndex],
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            showSelectedLabels: false,
            showUnselectedLabels: false,
            onTap: onTabTapped,
            currentIndex: selectedIndex,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Ionicons.home_outline),
                label: "Home",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Ionicons.list_outline),
                label: "TODO",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Ionicons.time_outline),
                label: "TIME TABLE",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Ionicons.person_outline),
                label: "ABOUT",
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      void onTabTapped(int index) {
        setState(() {
          selectedIndex= index;
        });
      }}
```

and call this inside routes in main.dart