# How to Hide Bottom Navigation Bar When Navigating to a Cart Screen Using Provider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm working on a Flutter app that utilizes the provider package for state management, including navigation state control through a bottom navigation bar. Specifically, I want to hide the BottomNavBar when navigating to the cart screen. I'm currently developing an e-commerce app in Flutter that features a home screen with a bottom navigation bar. I've implemented a provider to manage the state, including a boolean value that determines whether the bottom navigation bar should be visible or hidden. However, I'm facing an issue where changes to this boolean value aren't reflecting in the widget.

[image: Here is the cart screen image]

Main.dart-

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => BottomNavServices(),
        ),
      ],
child : MyApp()
```

The provider class

```
class BottomNavServices extends ChangeNotifier {
  String? tabSelection = 'main';

  void setTabSelection(String selection) {
    Utils.mainListNav.currentState!.pushReplacementNamed('/$selection');
    tabSelection = selection;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool _isCartScreenActive = false;

  bool get isCartScreenActive => _isCartScreenActive;

  void setCartScreenActive(bool value) {
    _isCartScreenActive = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is the page where i navigate on the iconbutton

```
 return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColors.kWhiteColor,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: AppColors.kGrayColor.withOpacity(0.5),
            // spreadRadius: 3,
            offset: const Offset(3, 0),
            blurRadius: 2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Consumer<BottomNavServices>(
        builder: (context, bottomServices, child) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  bottomServices.setTabSelection('main');
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  bottomServices.tabSelection == 'main'
                      ? Icons.home
                      : Icons.home_outlined,
                  color: bottomServices.tabSelection == 'main'
                      ? AppColors.kPrimaryColor
                      : AppColors.kUnSelectedColor,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  bottomServices.setTabSelection('favorite');
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  bottomServices.tabSelection == 'favorite'
                      ? Icons.favorite
                      : Icons.favorite_border,
                  color: bottomServices.tabSelection == 'favorite'
                      ? AppColors.kPrimaryColor
                      : AppColors.kUnSelectedColor,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  bottomServices.setTabSelection('shoppingcart');
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  bottomServices.tabSelection == 'shoppingcart'
                      ? Icons.shopping_cart
                      : Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                  color: bottomServices.tabSelection == 'shoppingcart'
                      ? AppColors.kPrimaryColor
                      : AppColors.kUnSelectedColor,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  bottomServices.setTabSelection('profile');
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  bottomServices.tabSelection == 'profile'
                      ? Icons.person
                      : Icons.person_outline,
                  color: bottomServices.tabSelection == 'profile'
                      ? AppColors.kPrimaryColor
                      : AppColors.kUnSelectedColor,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Here is the cart screen

```
 ListView(
              children: [
                Consumer<ShoppingCartService>(
                  builder: (context, cartService, child) {
                    if (cartService.products.isEmpty) {
                      return const SizedBox();
                    }
                    return Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 20),
                          child: Text(
                            AppStrings.kCartSummary.toUpperCase(),
                            style: AppStyles.kCartSummaryTextStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                        buildSizedBoxHeight(20),
                        Container(
                          color: AppColors.kWhiteColor,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 10, top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                '${AppStrings.kSubTotal} (${cartService.numberOfQuantityInCart} ${cartService.itemPlurilization()})',
                                style: AppStyles.kSubTotalTextStyle,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                currency(
                                  context,
                                  cartService.getTotalPrice(),
                                ),
                                style: AppStyles.kGetTotalPriceTextStyle,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Consumer<ShoppingCartService>(
                    builder: (context, cartService, child) {
                      if (cartService.products.isEmpty) {
                        return Container(
                          width: 200,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.shopping_cart_rounded,
                                size: 50,
                                color: AppColors.kGrayColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                              ),
                              buildSizedBoxHeight(15),
                              Text(
                                AppStrings.kYourCartIsEmpty,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ),
                              buildSizedBoxHeight(15),
                              Text(
                                AppStrings.kYouHaveNotAddedAnyItemToYourCart,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      return ProductShoppingList(
                        productCart: cartService.products,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: cartService.products.isEmpty
              ? const SizedBox()
              : CheckOutButton(cartService: cartService),
        ),
```

Comment: I feel this can be easily handled if used `bottom_navy_bar` package

Comment: Okay...let me check the package and see how i can use it here..Thanks

Comment: [BottomNavigator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77149910/21296112) you may refer this